# Google Recaptcha Unresponsive Size

Tags: css, responsive-design, recaptcha

So i was developing a website at *[english-lesson.16mb.com](http://english-lesson.16mb.com)* , after a hard work making the registration form using css so it can be responsive on all devices, i put the google recaptcha with hope it become responsive, but the truth i faced is google recaptcha has fixed size.

[image: Unresponsive google recaptcha]

I tried adding `style="width:50%;"` or any kind like that , but it only change something invisible not the box itself

Orange : actual size of invisible thing before style
Blue   : now

[image: Style Changing]

The point i asking this is , if i using smaller screen , the verify button will be cropped from view

[image: Cropped]

I don't want to put horizontal scroll neither overflow-x or anything like that , is there any way to change the size of google recaptcha ?

live preview : *[english-lesson.16mb.com/register.php](http://english-lesson.16mb.com/register.php)*

Comment: you are checking in a device with width 176 px i think.. thats wrong.. RWD goes only till 300 or 320px ..

Comment: @SahilDhir , i still need it to be responsive at 176px

Comment: @user6668201 may I ask why? Like Sahil said, screen sizes below 320 usually aren't of much concern. What are you building for? An Apple Watch? Even that is at the very least 272px.

Comment: @QuangdaoNguyen , lets make an example , apple watch now have browser as powerful as android / windows browser , of course they will be the best seller ( maybe more than android / windows sale that year ) , but if they cannot enjoy surfing the web because some of them blocking low resolution or having bad design , they will suffer , and i don't want any of my web visitor is suffered because my web design . - Google Translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue with recaptcha v2. It is not responsive by default. After having some googling I can manage to do it with some css hack. First keep in mind you need to add the recaptcha in Automatic rendering not Explicit rendering. [look here](http://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display).

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key"></div>
```

Add below css in style

```
@media screen and (max-width: 455px){ #rc-imageselect, .g-recaptcha { transform:scale(0.71); -webkit-transform:scale(0.71); transform-origin:0 0; -webkit-transform-origin:0 0; }}
```